# The Art of Computer Programming, Vol 4, Fascicle 2 typo?

Tags: knuth, taocp

At the bottom of page 5 is the phrase "changes *k* to *k* ⊕ (1<sup>*j*+1</sup>)<sub>2</sub>". Isn't 1 to any power still 1 even in binary? I'm thinking this must be a typo. I sent an email to Dr. Knuth to report this, but I don't expect to hear back for months. In the meantime, I'm trying to figure out what this is supposed to be.

Comment: Voting to close as "not programming related." Hehe, I kid.

Comment: For those of us who don't have a copy in front of us, to figure out what it is supposed to be we need a little more info

Comment: I didn't think Dr. Knuth /used/ email...

Comment: Adrian: I'm presuming that only people who have the book will answer the question.

Comment: Arcane: Yes, Dr. Knuth stopped using email on 1/1/90. But there's an address for reporting errors in taocp. His secretary prints the emails and gives them to him. http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/email.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be resolved by using the convention that (...)<sub>2</sub> represents a bitwise representation. (1<sup>j+1</sup>)<sub>2</sub> then consists solely of j+1 ones, rather than referring to an exponentiation. You can see this convention explained more explicitly in TAOCP Volume 4 Fascicle 1 at page 8, for example:

> If x is almost any nonzero 2-adic
>   integer, we can write its bits in the
>   form
>
> x =
>   (g01<sup>a</sup>10<sup>b</sup>)<sub>2</sub>
>
> in other words, x consists of some 
>   arbitrary (but infinite) binary string
>   g, followed by a 0, which is followed 
>   by a+1 ones and followed by b zeros, 
>   for some a >= 0 and b >= 0.

[I have substituted the symbol alpha by g to save encoding problems]

Going back to your original query;
k ⊕(1<sup>j+1</sup>)<sub>2</sub> is equated with k ⊕ (2<sup>j+1</sup> - 1)
implying that (1<sup>j+1</sup>)<sub>2</sub> = (2<sup>j+1</sup> - 1): this holds because the left-hand side is the integer whose significant bits are j+1 (contiguous) ones; the right-hand side is an exponentiation. For example, with j =3:

(1<sup>4</sup>)<sub>2</sub> = (1111)<sub>2</sub> = (2<sup>4</sup> - 1)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A list of known typos can be found on the errata page:

http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html

Your reported typo is not there. If it really is a typo, you might be eligible for a cash reward from Knuth himself.

Comment: He doesn't actually do the checks any more, because it exposes checking account etc.  now you get a certificate.  Hardly anyone cashed the checks anyway: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/news08.html